# Unicode in Flask-Restful API and JSON issue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, unicode

I've met an odd issue related to the unicode in ajax requests to the Flask-Restful API server. The issue appears only on one machine, but not another.

I have a restful class. As you may note the characters fields are set to unicode.

```
class PostListApi(Resource):
def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('body', type = unicode, required = True, help = 'No description provided', location = 'json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('longitude', type = float, required = False, help = 'Unknown address', location = 'json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('latitude', type = float, required = False, help = 'Unknown address', location = 'json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('address', type = unicode, required = True, help = 'No address specified', location = 'json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('scheduled', type = str, required = True, help = 'Not scheduled correctly', location = 'json')
        super(PostListApi, self).__init__()
```

My issue is that when I send an ajax request with latin characters in the BODY, the server replies with the 400 error.

```
Request URL:
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 BAD REQUEST
Request Headersview source
Accept:undefined
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Content-Length:159
**Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8**
Proxy-Authorization:Basic a3lyeWxvLnlhdHNlbmtvOnBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNDU2
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview parsed
{"body":"this is a test","address":"141 Rue Saint-Martin, 75003 Paris, France","longitude":2.351530499999967,"latitude":48.8614575,"scheduled":"20131017 1000"}
```

But when the data is in cyrilic alphabet the server manages the request properly.

```
Request URL:
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Request Headersview source
Accept:undefined
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Content-Length:208
**Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8**
Cookie:
Proxy-Authorization:Basic a3lyeWxvLnlhdHNlbmtvOnBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNDU2
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
{body:Ð™Ð½ Ð½ÐµÐ·Ð» Ð½Ð¾Ð¶Ñ‚Ñ€ÑŽÐ´ Ð¾Ñ„Ñ„ÑÐ½Ð´Ð¹Ñ‚ Ð²ÑÑˆ,…}
address: "Ð™Ð½ Ð½ÐµÐ·Ð» Ð½Ð¾Ð¶Ñ‚Ñ€ÑŽÐ´ Ð¾Ñ„Ñ„ÑÐ½Ð´Ð¹Ñ‚ Ð²ÑÑˆ"
body: "Ð™Ð½ Ð½ÐµÐ·Ð» Ð½Ð¾Ð¶Ñ‚Ñ€ÑŽÐ´ Ð¾Ñ„Ñ„ÑÐ½Ð´Ð¹Ñ‚ Ð²ÑÑˆ"
latitude: 48.8614575
longitude: 2.351530499999967
scheduled: "20131017 1000"
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:51
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 17 Oct 2013 08:03:41 GMT
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
```

Request generation is done with the ajax method of jquery

```
function ajaxRequest(uri, method, data){
    var request = {
                url: uri,
                type: method,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                accepts: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                //data: data != null?((method == 'GET') ? $.param(data): utf8_encode(JSON.stringify(data))):null,
                data: data != null?((method == 'GET') ? $.param(data): JSON.stringify(data)):null,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {},
                error: function(jqXHR) {
                    console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
                }
            };
    return $.ajax(request);
```

Have you met a similar issue before? How can this be tackled? I suppose that the latin characters must also be encoded to unicode before sending to the server. How could I force jquery to encode everything into unicode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'when the data is in cyrilic alphabet the server manages the request properly.' Judging by the third piece of code you've posted when you send things in cyryllic the server responds with 500 code - Internal Server Error, so this is not ok either. Is that PostListApi class all you have on server? How about some routes and view functions?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. The server doesn't respond with 500 code if the text is **in** cyrilic. The 400 error (parameter not found) occures when the text is in latin (first request example).

Comment: @ryzhiy: response contains `"Status Code:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"`. How did you get it? How do you generates the output, could you show `repr()` instead?

Answer (score 7):

I use follow code and I don't have this problem and problem with output

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from flask.ext.restful.representations.json import output_json
output_json.func_globals['settings'] = {'ensure_ascii': False, 'encoding': 'utf8'}
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
...
```